# Vuex dynamic modules are not being namespaced

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm working with a modular vue application that registers the modules at compile time. Please see the code below -

**app.js**

```
import store from './vue-components/store';

var components = {
    erp_inventory: true,
    erp_purchase: true,
};

// Inventory Module Components
if (components.erp_inventory) {
    // erp_inventory.
    store.registerModule('erp_inventory', require('./erp-inventory/vue-components/store'));
    // erp_inventory/product_search_bar
    store.registerModule([ 'erp_inventory', 'product_search_bar' ], require('./erp-inventory/vue-components/store/products/search-bar'));
}
```

**./erp-inventory/vue-components/store/index.js**

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state() {
        return {};
    },
    getters: {},
    actions: {}
}
```

**./erp-inventory/vue-components/store/products/search-bar/index.js**

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state() {
        return {
            supplier_id
        };
    },
    getters: {
        supplier_id: (state) => {
            return state.supplier_id;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        set_supplier_id({ commit }, supplier_id) {
            commit('set_supplier_id', supplier_id);
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        set_supplier_id(state, supplier_id) {
            state.supplier_id = supplier_id;
        }
    }
}
```

When I use `context.$store.dispatch('erp_inventory/product_search_bar/set_supplier_id', e.target.value, {root:true});` to dispatch the action in search-bar/index.js, vue is unable to find the namespace stating `[vuex] unknown action type: erp_inventory/product_search_bar/set_supplier_id`

I've read the documentation of vuex and dynamic modules and even though I've set `namespaced: true,` in each store, this problem persists. After dumping the store of my app I found that `namespaced` was never being set for registered modules (see image below).

[image: Namespaced is false]

Unless I'm doing something wrong, could it be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use require(....).default, otherwise you won't get the default export pc fro your ES6 module file, but object by webpack that's wrapping it.

Comment: This worked, the dispatch works, namespace are now proper. Thanks a lot!